# How to convert text in Chiwriter to Word

Tags: ms-word, format, converters

I have some old (from 1991) texts written in Chiwriter. I would like to convert them to Word format. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: This is a programmer website for questions about code, not about tools or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend finding a website or a conversion program (like [AutoHotKey](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18346/AutoHotkey-Getting-Started.html)) that will rewrite the ChiWriter files into a Microsoft Word document.  Doing it via program so may prove to be difficult on newer operation systems because they will not run programs of that age.  If that is the case see if you can use the program in a virtual machine and convert them from there.
A similar question was asked / answered [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28935568/Convert-ChiWriter-file-to-txt-or-doc.html).  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If they are ChiWriter version 3 files, try http://www.colinandmargaret.co.uk/CW2RTF/CW2RTF.html for Win10 or WinXP platform. It creates RTF files which can be read directly by Word.